# Does ConTeXt have any limits to how many items can be used in a document?

Tags: context

Does ConTeXt have any limits to how many items can be used in a document? Is there a maximum restriction on the number of macros, footnotes, cross-references, or counters that can appear in a document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no hardcoded limits. Of course, your system's memory gives an upper limit on how much memory TeX can use.